# Changing Transparent Background to White in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, png, density-independent-pixel

Please consider the following piece of Matlab code:

```
  MyImage = imread('a.png');
  imwrite(MyImage, 'a.jpg', 'jpg');
```

The problem I am facing is that a.png has a transparent background. When I save it as jpg, it saves the image with black background.

Kindly please them me how to make the background white. I need to do this programmatically since I have 1000s of files to process.

I would prefer if you could write me the code, since I am not very proficient with Matlab.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
I = imread('file.png', 'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1]);
imwrite(I, 'file.jpg')
```

Comment: @Haider: could you post a sample PNG image (with transparent background) so we can experiment with...